# jQuery - output scrollLeft when horizontally scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a codepen here - https://codepen.io/mt-ttmt/pen/VxYmbG

It's a simple container with a wider container inside that scroll left to right.

How do I out the scrollLeft position of the inner container when scrolling left to right

```
$(function(){

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log($('.content').scrollLeft());
  })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some small changes. This seems to be working:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJbRGj

```
$(window).on('scroll mousewheel', function(){
   console.log($('.content').position().left); 
});
```

Comment: Is mousewheel a plugin

Comment: @ttmt No, it is fired when operating a mouse wheel or similar devices.

Comment: So it comes as standard with jQuery, I'm using 3.2.1 I think

Comment: @ttmt Yes, it's basic jQuery. (PS If this answer works for you, please mark it as accepted.)